# Circular Linked List: NullPointerException Error

Tags: java, circular-list

Getting a NullPointerException error in the print statement, it is printing everything i input and need in the driver. But right after it causes the NullPointException error. I need this to work, I can not make any more methods afterwards because of this error.

I have a test on this tmr and I have no clue why it's causing this exception error. Please help! Thank you.

What I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StringNode 
{
//attributes
private String data;
private StringNode link;
//nodes counter
int numNodes =0;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

//constructor
public StringNode(String iData, StringNode iLink)
{
data = iData;
link = iLink;
}

//create empty list 
StringNode list = null;



//*********Create method: addToFrontFILI
public void addToFrontBM(String newN)
{
list = new StringNode(newN, list);
System.out.println("A node has been added to the front.");
numNodes++;
System.out.println("NumNodes:" +numNodes);
}

//---------------------Works but causes Nullpointer Exception------------
//Create method: printLLFILI
public void printLLBM() 
{
StringNode tptr = list;

while(tptr.link != list)
{
System.out.println(tptr.data);
tptr = tptr.link;
}

System.out.println(tptr.data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tptr = tptr.link;` this line will assign the last `null` element to `tptr`, but the `while` only checks `tptr.link`, this will cause a NullPointerException. update the code to:

```
while( tptr != null && tptr.link != list)
```

Comment: I understand this, I can't really use null because the program is supposed to work as one circular link. My professor is being very strict about using null this way.

Comment: from the code snippt, it's not really a  circular.  actually loop ends with null not the circular list. if it's a cirular, there should be no null in the  circular list.  `list = new StringNode(newN, list);` when inserting the first element, the list is null, then, when insert second, it should turn this null to circular.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code,you have not do anything when `tptr` is null,when `tptr` is null,then NPE will occur.

```
while(tptr.link != list)
{
  System.out.println(tptr.data);
  tptr = tptr.link;
}
```

You can change to below:

```
while(tptr!=null && tptr.link != list)
{
  System.out.println(tptr.data);
  tptr = tptr.link;
}
```

Comment: My professor does not want us to use null, except for when creating the empty list.

Comment: is there any possible way to do this without making tptr null?

Comment: You must check if it null otherwise `NullPointerException` will occur,if you do not want to use it,then you use `Optional` from `java8`

Comment: even when I did try to replace the code, I still receive the same error at the same location.

Comment: Based on your code the only place to throw `NullPointerException` is at `tptr.link != list` when `tptr` is null,after you change your code,the exception should not happen and must not happen